# How to recreate this text stroke/weight design in Photoshop or Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, text, stroke

I have been trying to replicate this design without success. I have tried duplicating the object and scaling it up a bit, I also tried using the *FX Stroke* option.

This is what I want to recreate:

[image: design image]

Attempt 1: Duplicating the object and scaling it up a bit

[image: attempt 1]

Attempt 2: Using the *Stroke* option in *FX* (outline achieved, but font needs a bit of work):

[image: attempt 2]

I believe that they are using [Varela Round](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Varela+Round) as a typeface.

Comment: Use illustrator offset.

Comment: Position: Outside instead of inside. I think that the part between the `r` and the `z` is added after on a layer below the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in Illustrator:

- Select your text and convert to outlines via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
- With the resulting object selected, go to 'Object → Path → Offset Path', tick the 'Preview' on and play with the settings here
- Hit 'Ok', then do a 'Pathfinder → Unite', then send this to back via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and apply a different colour
- Then some more manual tweaking might be needed to join some of the points to further simplify the resulting outline